# Hostel in Barcelona near Sonar festival night site

Tags: accommodation, hostels, barcelona

I'm traveling to Barcelona to Sonar festival and I would like to find a hostel near the [night festival site](http://sonar.es/en/2013/pg/how-to-get-there_193#.Uadv3bTR6hO).  Is there a hostel within a 20 minute walking distance?

Comment: What would you class as "near"? Would any hostel in downtown Barcelona be acceptable, or are you wanting one say, within walking distance?